# Show $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ represent holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, represent holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.

**(Weierstrass test)** Let $f_n : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions with $|f_n(x)| \le M_n$ for all $x \in I$ and $k=1,2, \dots$. If $\sum_n M_n$ converges then $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly on $I$.

I get the idea is to find $M_n$ such that
$$\left|(-1)^n\dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|
= \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!}|z|^{2n+1}\leq  |z|^{2n+1}$$
is less than. Do I assume that $|z|\leq R$? If so, the only way the geometric series formula works is if I restrict $R$ even more. Is that correct?

Comment: And why does the UC of the series for $|z|<R$ for all $R$ imply that the series represents an analytic function?

Comment: What is UC mean?

Comment: UC = Uniform Convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that's the series for sine. This doesn't actually converge uniformly on the whole complex plane I don't think. But, you can do something a little tricky. You take just a disk of some radius. It will converge uniformly ON THAT DISK, and so you can prove it is analytic on that disk as the limit of a uniformly converging sequence of analytic functions. Since being analytic is a local condition, this prove that the function is analytic at any point in the complex plane (not including infinity).

Comment: It is but we are to prove that sine is analytic using the series expression. So I don't use Weierstrass  test?

Comment: You have to combine Weierstrass test with the fact that a power series is differentiable inside the circle of convergence. In this case the radius of convergence is $\infty$ because R is arbitrary.

Comment: You'll use the Weirstrass test, but in order to be able togenerate the series for it you should do it within some circle of radius $R$. Then you can bound the size of the terms by $\frac{R^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$